# foursquare invalid_oauth error for /v2/checkins/add

Tags: oauth-2.0, foursquare

After successfully acquiring an oauth_token for a user, I am able to get successful response from endpoints such as:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

However, when I try and add a check-in via the following post:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add

venueId=4d234b5bf7a9a1438f1a479f&shout=sdfasdfasdfasdf&oauth_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

I receive the following response:

{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}

Has anyone else noticed a problem using your oauth_token for some API endpoints but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that somehow you're not correctly passing POST params. OAuth token is the first parameter we check for in any given request, and so even if you were missing all of your params, you'd see the error for the oauth_token.

I'd double check that you're correctly passing your POST params.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't specifying the content-type header in my post, adding that fixed it.


Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @smehmood - Could you please paste the code to support your answers ?